# Why does my reflected dictionary type not implement IDictionary?

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm doing some generic object comparison, using reflection and recursion. The recursive method needs some type information in each step, which is given by the caller. At one point I know that the next property is a `Dictionary<T,U>`, and I want to send the correct type. I came up with this:

```
Type dictionaryType = typeof (IDictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(new [] {keyType.PropertyType, typeof(ValueType)});
```

Where `keyType` and `ValueType` are types found out earlier. However, this type does not implement the `IDictionary<KeyType, ValueType>` interface, according to `dictionaryType.GetInterfaces()`. Why? It *looks* like it should...

Comment: Please work that into a small complete code snippet.

Comment: You're making a `typeof(IDictionary<KeyType, ValueType>)` object. That's an interface type. It can't implement itself.

Comment: @Henk: Really, why? The question is more of a theoretical one, I'd say, and being runnable wouldn't give much information

Comment: Because with this kind of questions it is usually something in the way dictionaryType.GetInterfaces() is used. But it looks like rich.o has your answer and it is not the case here.

Comment: Reflection and generics are irrelevant here. What does this expression return, for example: `typeof(IConvertible).GetInterfaces().Count()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the type IS `IDictionary<KeyType, ValueType>`. The `GetInterfaces` method only promises to return `An array of Type objects representing all the interfaces implemented or inherited by the current Type`. Since `IDictionary<>` does not (and indeed cannot) implement itself, the return value is legitimately all interfaces it inherits.

Using `Dictionary<,>` as an arbitrary class that implements `IDictionary<,>`, the following would be more appropriate:

```
Type dictionaryType = typeof (Dictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(new [] {keyType.PropertyType, typeof(ValueType)});
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense, now that you've explained it. Thanks :)